# The game loop designing

Tags: c++

[There](https://gameprogrammingpatterns.com/game-loop.html) is the simple game loop proposal:

```
double previous = getCurrentTime();
double lag = 0.0;
while (true)
{
  double current = getCurrentTime();
  double elapsed = current - previous;
  previous = current;
  lag += elapsed;

  processInput();

  while (lag >= MS_PER_UPDATE)
  {
    update();
    lag -= MS_PER_UPDATE;
  }

  render();
}
```

I think that the solution do have one serous drawback. Let's assume that (in some rather very uncommon case) the lag is about as huge as 3 seconds. In such a case if the *MS_PER_UPDATE == 16msec (1/(60 fps))* the `update` function in internal loop (`while (lag >= MS_PER_UPDATE)`) will run 180 times! Taking into consideration that the `update` function may take some not very large but still decent time needed to there will be a significant.

Wouldn't the following:

```
double previous = getCurrentTime();
double lag = 0.0;
while (true)
{
  double current = getCurrentTime();
  double elapsed = current - previous;
  previous = current;
  lag += elapsed;

  processInput();

  if (lag >= MS_PER_UPDATE)
  {
    update(lag);
    lag = 0;
  }

  render();
}
```

solution be better?

Here instead of calling the render function 180 time I call the render only ONCE but with lag as a parameter. And inside the render the game objects are updated (say moved) proportionally to the vale of the passed lag so if for. e.g. the lag was 5 times > then the default fps (1/60) we just move all objects 5x instead of 1x?

Comment: Read this series of posts [Fix Your Timestep!](https://gafferongames.com/post/fix_your_timestep/)  With your proposal a bullet would fly through a player without colliding; or object collisions would happen inside each other etc.

Comment: There are ways to prevent excessive updates without variable timestep. You can just limit the updates to N per frame.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The whole point of games loops with fixed-size step is to decouple rendering and physics to retain stability, determinism in face of variable FPS.

You cannot simply update physics with 5 times larger step and expect it to be equal to updating 5x with the original step. That is simply not possible. With high enough step, numerical calculations will break down - fast collisions will be missed, objects will clip into each other, some might "explode".

So yes, you can go back to variable-sized time step of course, but you will get back all the drawbacks due to which it was abandoned.

Comment: Ok I thing i understand the drawbacks of the variable-sized time step proposed in the second solution, BUT am i right that the first solution will seriously freeze/hang the game when the lag be decent (as I've stated 180 `render` calls in case of 3 sec. lag) ?

Comment: @darro911 `update` calls? Well that depends on what happens in `update`, right. If you simply do not have the computational budget to run the game at 60FPS,UPS , there isn't much you can to do to "fix" it. What you can do is to just drop frames - e.g. cap the `while` loop to 5 iterations and zero-out `lag` after. This will slow the game down, while keeping physics stable. You can also experiment what is acceptable maximal `MS_PER_UPDATE` which keeps physics stable.

Comment: @darro911  Re lag - unless you are writing a multi-player game with servers on the internet you should not have excessive lag.  If a single player game has this much lag you have bug(s) and need to fix them.

Comment: @RichardCritten. Ok but theoretically I'm right that in case of 3 sec. lag the update will be called about 180 times (considering 60 fps)? Am I?

Comment: If you have 3 seconds of "lag" in a single player game the the game is broken.  Dealing with 3 seconds of lag in a multi-user server authoritative game would require a client state refresh from the server.  In neither case would the rendering / physics loop on the client be executed to catch up.

Comment: @Quimby I'm talking here more about almost pure hypothetically large lag. I just would like my code to work correctly also in such edge cases. Ok i know I can just impose a loop cap BUT that cause the game to skip some frames resulting in NOT fluent gameplay.

Comment: @darro911 if you have 3sec lag, you will not have fluent gameplay. What do you even think would be source of this lag? 180calls is potentially nothing, you can make millions of them every seconds easily, just depends on what is inside.

Comment: @RichardCritten "In neither case would the rendering / physics loop on the client be executed to catch up" You mean just because in such a case the game would probably freeze for some, absolutely not acceptable time? Yes?

Comment: @darro911No this is all after the freeze - Single player 3 secs of lag - fix the game.  Multi-player authoritative server the client needs to ask the server for the full game state as there is no way the client can know what other players have been doing in the last 3 seconds (see rubber-banding, ghost-blocks etc)

Comment: @RichardCritten "No this is all after the freeze" what do You mean "after the freeze"?

Comment: @Quimby Ok but if I'd like to limit the max  update calls to `n` times to prevent the excessive game lag/freeze how would i know what concrete value should it be. On one fast computer the update function ma take 100 times shorter than on some slower/older system?

Comment: @darro911 Then use time instead of `n`. I still have no idea how can 3s lag happen in your game? Really sounds like a bug in the first time.

Comment: @Quimby "Then use time instead of n" so for e.g. I can just measure the total time the   the catch-up loop have taken so far and if the time exceeds for ex. 60 fps (for the fluent gameplay) just break the catch-up loop skipping some updates but letting the game to runs without freezes/lags(by preventing to stay in the loop too long)?

Comment: @darro911 Sure, but it will lag for those 3 seconds, right?

Comment: @Quimby no, that 3 secs. is PURELY hypothetical.  I haven't even implemented render function yet! As I've said  I just would like to ensure my code will work correctly also in such edge cases.